# Progress bar in Android

Tags: android

At the time of application installation i need to set the progress bar .How to create this?
 thanks in advance !!

Note:
I have the Android application.When i Install that application it will take some time to install at that time i wish to show some Progress Message.Is it Possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the time of application installation"? What do you mean by "i need to set the progress bar"? What specifically are you expecting to "create"?

Comment: I have the Android application.When i Install that application it will take some time to install at that time i wish to show some Progress Message.Is it Possible?

Comment: Short of replacing system software, I doubt it.